# getchar() workaround in c/c++ in order to redirect output

Tags: cmd, getchar, output-redirect

I have an executable which is written in c++ and i run it in cmd.exe on Windows

When i run this executable and by looking at the source code, i can see that a use of `getchar()` function is made - The program asks the user to "click any key to continue" and i can see that `getchar()` is called so the program dosent continue until the user clicks any key.

My problem is that the program's output is too long so i want to redirect it to a file...(with the redirection character `>`)

So when i run the exe like this in cmd.exe:

```
prg > temp.txt
```

The program gets stuck, i assume that its because it waits for an input ( i tried clicking any key but it dosent work.)

When i run the program without redirecting it to a file, all works fine so long i press any key when prompted...

I would have just erased all `getchar()` calls but **I CANNOT** change the source code because i dont have all the resources in order to re-compile it.

Is there a workaround to my problem?

Comment: Not sure about Windows but on Linux you can pipe the input into the program.

Comment: as 4386427 noted, on linux it would be 'echo "k" | program > out_file'
Try something like this in windows (i dont have windows atm)

Comment: @Avra Are you sure it calls `getchar` and not some other specific function like [`_getch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx)?

Comment: I am sure, it calls `getchar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar` typically uses buffered input. That is, from a user's perspective, it doesn't wait for any key, but rather waits for the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once for each `getchar` that the program does. Or alternatively, the first time it does `getchar` (though you can only guess when it is, because there is no prompt), enter a long string:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Once you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the subsequent 30 `getchar` invocations will get `a`, the next one will get `\n`, and the next one will hang, waiting for more input (but there will be no prompt).

Another possible way you could make it work: redirect some input to your program:

```
echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | prg > temp.txt
```

Make sure you have enough input to satisfy all `getchar` calls.

Comment: If i understood correctly, i still need to guess when is the first `getchar`, and then press 'enter' or just press 'enter' indefinitely

Comment: @Avra That is why programs like `yes` exists `yes ''` will print infinite newlines and can be used in a pipeline: `yes '' | prg > temp.txt`